Get-AzStorageBlob : This request is not authorized to perform this operation
I am running Get-AzStorageBlob command in runbook.
Automation Account has Storage Blob Data Contributor role. Using system assigned managed identity.
But I am getting this error:
Get-AzStorageBlob : This request is not authorized to perform this operation.

commands executed
`$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -UseConnectedAccount

 $blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Context $ctx | Select-Object -Property Name`


Check if below provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?


This request is not authorized to perform this operation.

The above error occurs when you don't have proper permission or if there is a network setting which might be blocking the access to the storage account.
Check the network setting in portal.
Portal:

You can refer this MS-Document, If it connects with selected networks or private endpoints.
In my environment, I created automation account given Storage Blob Data Contributor role to system managed identity.
Portal:

Now I run below script in azure automation to get the list of blobs.
Script:
$subscription = "xxxx"
$identity = "1xxx"
$storageAccountName = "venkat6781"
$containerName = "test"

$null = Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process # Ensures you do not inherit an AzContext in your runbook
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId $identity).context  # Connect to Azure with user-assigned managed identity
$connectionResult = Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext
$connectionResult

$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -UseConnectedAccount
$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Context $ctx | Select-Object -Property Name

foreach ($blob in $blobs) {
    Write-Output $blob.Name
}

Output:
Name               : Default
Subscription       : 158bxxxxxxdd048f
Account            : 1b3bxfb4f9c755bxxxx
Environment        : AzureCloud
Tenant             : 226xxd40283xxx
TokenCache         : 
VersionProfile     : 
ExtendedProperties : {}
001.csv
002.csv
003.csv
004.csv
sample.mp4


Reference:
Using a system-assigned managed identity for an Azure Automation account | Microsoft Learn
